# ¿Cómo saber qué cantidad de monedas debo devolver en C?

Tags: c++, c, math

Un ejercicio me pide que debo imprimir la cantidad de monedas utilizadas al darle cambio a una persona.

Las monedas que tengo son de 25, 10, 5 y 1 centavos.

Me pide que ingrese un número que sería el cambio que tengo que devolver, y que, utilizando las monedas, cuente la cantidad de cada una a utilizar para devolver el valor ingresado.

Por ejemplo, si tengo que devolver 41 centavos, tendría que utilizar 1 moneda de 25 centavos, 1 de 10 centavos, 1 de 5 centavos y 1 de 1 centavo. Y así con cualquier valor que ingrese.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int q = 25;
    int d = 10;
    int n = 5;
    int p = 1;

    float m;
    do
    {
        m = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (m < 0);

    int c = round(m * 100);

    printf("%i\n", c);

}
```

Gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme.

P.D.: Estoy utilizando un IDE de un curso que estoy haciendo de CS50x Harvard.

Comment: Tienes el valor X a devolver. Tienes la denominación más alta A1, divide el vuelto por ella y tienes la cant. monedas de esa denominación C1. Luego, haces módulo de X por A1 y te dara el residuo X1 (lo que queda por resolver de X quitando C1) y así sucesivamente hasta que el residuo sea cero.

Comment: Ven aca y todas las monedas se asume que tienen una cantidad infinita?

Comment: Ese algoritmo es un *greedy algorithm* que no siempre da la respuesta más óptima, e. g. para las denominaciones 1, 15, 25, y el cambio 30, el algoritmo devolvería 1 moneda de 25 y 5 monedas de 1. Pero claro está que lo más óptimo serían 2 monedas de 15. Quizá la programación dinámica sea una mejor opción

Comment: Ya me salió el ejercicio, gracias igual. Saludos.

Comment: @arielberinstein estaría buenísimo que añadieras la respuesta con lo que hiciste para resolverlo. Con eso, otros podrían resolver el mismo problema en el futuro... y después, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: @Alfabravo, no voy a publicar la respuesta porque debo respetar la política de honestidad académica ya que es un ejercicio de un curso. Si alguien tiene alguna duda puede preguntar, y le ayudaré con gusto.

Comment: Hm, entiendo y celebro tu responsabilidad. De todas formas, suena feo que no haya *nada* que compartir a los que, en el curso o no, tengan un problema como el tuyo. Es todo. :)

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con un contador que guarde las iteraciones de cada variable (q,d,n,p) con la sentencia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int m=45;
    int q=25;
    int d=10;
    int n=5;
    int p=1;
    int z=1;
    int contq=0,contd=0,contn=0,contp=0;
    while(z!=0) {
        if(m%q==0) {
            contq++;
            m-=q;
        }
        else if(m%d==0) {
            contd++;
            m-=d;
        }
        else if(m%n==0) {
            contn++;
            m-=n;
        }
        else if(m%p==0) {
            contp++;
            m-=p;
        }
        if(m==0){
            z=0;
        }
    }
    printf("50=%d 25=%d 5=%d 1=%d",contq,contd,contn,contp);
}
```

Que el contador te de la cantidad de monedas.